# ListView OnItemClickListener doesn't fire

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm at a loss.
I have a ListView being set via adapter in a fragment.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_knowledgebase, container, false);

    // Set the adapter
    mListView = (AbsListView) view.findViewById(R.id.searchResultList);


    // Set OnItemClickListener so we can be notified on item clicks
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    return view;
}


public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (null != mCallback) {
       //call back to activity
        mCallback.onFragmentInteraction(position);
    }
}
```

The layout of the list is dead simple. Only 1 text view, no buttons or check boxes.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/searchResultList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
   />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"/>
```

I've set focusable properties to false and still no dice

Comment: `if (null != mCallback) {}` What is `mCallBack` in this line?

Comment: mCallback = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity; It is a link back to the activity wich hosts fragment

Comment: Turns out I misunderstood how ListView layout works. I thought that in order to make custom list I needed to modify this default list. Turns out I needed to create custom layout for list item and inflate that in Custom adapter...

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is your variable `mCallback` is null. So the code below this is not triggering...

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
  if (null != mCallback) {
    //call back to activity
     mCallback.onFragmentInteraction(position);
  }
}
```

this is almost this

```
 if (null != null) {
```

**to check my answer, try this:**

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
  Log.e("ListView OnItemClick","Clicked");
  if (null != mCallback) {
    //call back to activity
     mCallback.onFragmentInteraction(position);
  }
}
```

This will log **`ListView OnItemClick Clicked`**

Comment: Not the case either. Ididnt copy all my code in question earlier, but  mCallback gets set in public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallback = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } 
    }  I went ahead and tried your solution anyway and it still does not trigger.

Comment: `<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"/>`

is this your listview row item?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it should be onListItemClick

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
```